# ical-buddy for Ubuntu

Tags: calendar, conky, google-calendar, gnome-calendar

I just moved from Mac to Ubuntu (with budgie desktop). I cannot find any command-line tool like [ical-buddy](https://hasseg.org/icalBuddy/) which I can use to programmatically add or delete calendar events. I want to create a script that can be used by a desktop widget (conky) like [this](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1006349). I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ics-related libraries. For example `python3-icalendar` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python3-icalendar) maybe used as base.

If you need scripting for Google Calendar - use `gcalcli` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcalcli&searchon=names).

Also take look at https://rainlendar.net.